# What should I say when people say "thanks a lot"

Tags: politeness

When I help others, they say "thanks a lot". What should I say to reply to them?

Comment: I would usually  say, "You're welcome". There are other possibilities but that works in any situation.

Comment: Formal: You're (quite) welcome. More informal: No problem.

Comment: "De nada!" will work too, in most of the US.

Comment: Of course, if someone says, in a dreary monotone, "Gee, thanks a lot", it's possible that they're being sarcastic, and likely the less said the better.

Comment: @tinysunlight you bet, anytime, no problem, sure, that's okay, all right, not at all...

Comment: You could answer "Don't mention it a lot."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No problem / No worries
- You're welcome
- Not at all
- It was / has been a pleasure
- Thank you, too

Answer (score 0):

You could respond with one of these:

> - You're welcome
> - Not at all
> - Anytime
> - No problem